# Access 2010 - Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have local Office 2010 installed on a notebook, running Win 8.1 Pro. On the NB I have an Access-Application. It works very well. It does what it should. The enduser have no local Office 2010 installed. The user have to connect to a TS (Terminal-Server), to work with Office.

So, after I was testing my App, I copied it and pasted it on the TS, with my login. So I was testing finaly, but during the test, it comes the `Data type mismatch`-Error...

In the application are some local tables and local queries. But via ODBC, there are some SQL-Server-Views also linked. The ODBC-Connenction has the same config on both Systems.

Why does the app works fine on my NB, but not on the TS? It's exactly the same app, just `Copy & Paste` from the NB to the TS.

Thank you.

Greetz
Vegeta_77

Comment: CTRL-Break and show the line of code in error. Have the 2 systems the same architecture? 32/64bits

Comment: I would check the references for the app you just put on the TS to see if anything is missing.

Comment: Try launching the application on TS (hold down shift key to prevent any startup code from running). Can you open the linked SQL server tables from Access? It sounds like the application does not have permissions or simpy cannot open the SQL server tables (you also don't mention where the instance of SQL server is running). So a 10 second test is required to ensure that the sql linked tables can be opened when you place the application on the TS server.

Comment: @Albert. Yes. I can open all with ODBC linked tables. Also all local tables and queries. The only one how I don't can open is the pivot-table. I forgot to tell you, that the Problem is with a pivot-table. Sorry.

Comment: @random. All references are there. On TS the same as on the "original".